# Vue.js - Cannot read property 'gameid' of undefined

Tags: vue.js

I am still new to vue.js and any help is appreciated. I am trying to create a data property object that takes the game id of a specific game for a casino I'm building. I specified the game id in the  element, however, upon loading the page, i am met with an `Cannot read property 'gameid' of undefined` in google chrome devtools. I don't understand why the  element is not accepting the game id. I specified the game id in `<game gameid={{$gameid}}` in Laravel, but this does not show up. I am still met with this error. what am I doing wrong?

play.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <game gameid="{{$gameid}}"></game>
</div>

<template id="game-template">

</template>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.0.3/vue-resource.js"></script>

<script src="../js/play.js"></script>

@endsection
```

play.js

```
Vue.component('game', {
  template: '#game-template',

  data() {
    ready: null;
  },

  props: ['gameid'],

  created: function() {
    this.$http.get('api/ready/games/'.this.gameid).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  },
});

new Vue({
    el: 'body'
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you have shortened your code, so I can only go by what you have written:

Firstly don't mount to `body`, just create a `div` with an `id` and mount to that, secondly `data` needs to `return` an object inside a component:

```
data(){
   return {
      ready: null;
   }
}
```

You are also concatenating with the `php` syntax (dot) rather than a plus, so it should be:

```
'api/ready/games/' + this.gameid
```

And if `gameid` is a number you should pass it using `v-bind`:

```
<game v-bind:gameid="{{$gameid}}"></game>
```

Hopefully, that will get you someway to solving your problem, here's a JSFiddle that seems to work fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/3h033p5q/

Comment: thanks! that jsfiddle did it. my code seems to be functioning the way i want it now.